# How to link an annotation in MapView to its calling pin

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Swift 4 iOS 11.x

Learning about mapViews and annotations and I can quite get my mind around some functionality I would like to do.

I create a mapView, and I add an annotation to it with a button, so far so good. I want the button to be a delete pin one, so it looks like this.

[image]

Now when I click on the blue no entry I want it to delete the black pin that it is connected too. But how to trace the link of the annotation to its pin. I get a call back with the button and thru the accessory view. I can lookup the title of the view and find the link, but surely there is a better method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this method `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)` of `MKMapViewDelegate`

**Something like this**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
             calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    //Here you have the annotation that was selected
    let selectedAnnotation = view.annotation
    //Do whatever you need here
}
```

Comment: If you want the pin then view is the AnnotationView, which is the pin itself @user3069232

Comment: So why when I execute this command  mapView.removeAnnotation((view.annotation)!) does it not delete the pin.

Comment: Stop Press, it works if I put in a single pin, but if I put in multiple pins I need to select and delete it twice? very odd...

Comment: only once, every callout will delete one annotation from the MapView right? @user3069232

Comment: Trying to figure out the sequence of events, but seems if I add more than one pin; The first time I click on the button, the annotation disappears but the pin remains, the second time I click on the same annotation the pin is deleted. I think it is linked with the button, I can create three pins, click on delete for each... won't work. But if I than click on delete again, they disappear!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167801/discussion-between-user3069232-and-reinier-melian).